# Refresh Theme() gives Array index out of bounds exception in lwuit

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-form

I am using lwuit for making the j2me mobiles app . And in one form i need to remove a component from a container and then have to add another component , And after doing this i am calling the refreshTheme() and revalidate() function, so that the changes on the form can be reflect on the screen, But sometime calling these function gives an error as "Array index out of bounds: 2>=2" or "Array index out of bounds 0>=0" . This error doesn't come always. 

So Are there any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when violating the EDT, you should use callSerially() when accessing LWUIT.